# Mimekit attachments not working with iOS email app

Tags: c#, email-attachments, mimekit

I'm using Mimekit to construct emails containing a PDF attachment.  This works well in every case, except when the recipient has an iPhone.  On an iPhone, the email appears in their inbox with a paperclip symbol next to it.  However when they open the email there is no attachment present.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can resolve this?

Regards,

Adam

Comment: https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/issues is the quickest way to contact its developers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the attachments to BodyBuilder.Attachments instead of BodyBuilder.LinkedResources.